# grails http post request with JSON data

Tags: json, grails, grails-controller

I am trying to send a POST request using grails. I have read various post already present but no success. I have done following stuff till now.

1. Created a new grails project using GGTS.
2. Created a controller
3. Installed Rest plugin for grails.
4. Made below changes in my grails controller.

   ```
   def index(){
    withHttp(uri: "http://127.0.0.1:3001") {
      def html = post(query : [q:'Groovy'])
      assert html.HEAD.size() == 1
      assert html.BODY.size() == 1
       }}
   ```
5. when I am trying to access the controller it breaks.

Am I doing anything wrong here. I am sending JSON data in POST request which would later be saved? Any pointers directions would be very helpful.

Comment: Please describe how your controller "breaks." A stack trace would be great.

Comment: I would suggest to use [rest client builder plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/rest-client-builder), if possible, for its simplistic DSL approach.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried doing this in a Grails controller but I figure since its groovy, it should work.

```
import groovyx.net.http.*
def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://127.0.0.1:3001' )
http.request( POST, JSON ) { req ->
     body = [q:'groovy']

     response.success = { resp, json ->
     // handle repsonse
     }
}
```

See more at: http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/json.html and
[Groovy HTTPBuilder POST: missing method(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555408/groovy-httpbuilder-post-missing-methods)